# Error: grep: find: Is a directory

Tags: linux, grep

I am new to Linux and going through some tutorials and samples. I created a file called `test` and put `alex` and `alexander` in it. I'm trying to find instances of just `alex`.

If I do `grep alex *` I get the error:

```
grep: find: Is a directory.
```

If I do `cat test | grep alex` then I get (as expected)

```
alex
alexander (with alex in red)
```

Why does the first cause an error, and the second produce expected results?

Comment: Your first example, `grep alex *`, will not produce the error `grep: find: Is a directory`. Please provide the actual command you are running, and the actual error message.

Comment: If I could add a screenshot I would.  grep alex * is giving me the error: "grep: find: Is a directory."

Comment: You don't need a screen shot. In fact, it is *not* preferred or desired. Also see [How to copy and paste from terminal with keyboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/761807/608639)

Comment: why was there disbelief regarding the output? I just ran into the exact same thing. Use of `*` led me to `is a directory` as output.

Comment: There could be a directory there called 'find' ;-)

Answer (score 14):

If you want to grep phrase from specific file use:

```
# grep "alex" test
```

In case you use `grep alex *` it will search through all files inside the current work directory. In case subdirectory will be met it will tell you something like `grep: find: Is a directory`
If you want to perform a recursive search use `-r` key. For example

```
# grep -r "alex" /some/folder/
```

In this case all files and files inside subdirectories from `/some/folder/` will be checked.
And you can always use `man grep`.

Comment: Show the output of `ls -al` from directory where file `test` is located

Comment: @Adoyt Because you have a directory named `find` in the directory from which you are running the command.

Comment: Here's the output for test. : [adoyt@CentOSVM ~]$ ls -al
total 3080
-rw-rw-r--.  1 adoyt adoyt      16 Jul 12 12:04 test

Answer (score 14):

The correct answer would be:

```bash
grep -d skip alex /etc/*
```

Comment: this is the real answer OP is looking for

Answer (score 3):

If you wanted to go through all the directories including the `find` directory, you can run this command:

```
grep alex * -r
```

Which will go through all the directories in your current directory recursively.

Answer (score 2):

Setting the environmental variable `GREP_OPTIONS` to include the value `"--directories=skip"` should suppress that “Is a directory” message (i.e. enter `GREP_OPTIONS="--directories=skip"` or add that line to one of your login initialization files like .bashrc to make that behavior permanent).

```
> cat test
alex
alexander

> grep alex *    
grep: mysql_data: Is a directory
grep: sql_updates: Is a directory
test:alex
test:alexander
grep: tmp_files: Is a directory

> GREP_OPTIONS="--directories=skip"

> grep alex *                      
test:alex
test:alexander
```

Also since there is a command named “test” and another named “find” it’s usually not advisable to use those as file or directory names. That shouldn’t be a problem here but it can lead to other conflicts.

Comment: `grep: warning: GREP_OPTIONS is deprecated; please use an alias or script`

Answer (score 0):

Or using `grep` with `-l` flag or `-w` flag

```
$ grep -l alex /etc/*
```

To return list of files containing word "alex" in the `/etc` directory

```
$ grep -w alex /etc/*
```

To return list of lines from files in the `/etc` directory containing "alex" word